# Related Rates Word Problem: Shadow of a falling rock

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So I'm doing my online homework on related rates, which is tedious and confusing to me as it is, and I run into this problem with no idea on how to do it. Can anyone help me understand the steps involved in this problem?

> [image]
>
> Suppose you have a street light at a height $H$. You drop a rock
>   vertically so that it hits the ground at a distance $d$ from the
>   street light. Denote the height of the rock by $h$. The shadow of the
>   rock moves along the ground. Let $s$ denote the distance of the shadow
>   from the point where the rock impacts the ground. Of course, $s$ and
>   $h$ are both functions of time. To enter your answer use the notation
>   $v$ to denote $h'$:
>
> $v=h'$.
>
> Then the speed of the shadow at any time while the rock is in the air
>   is given by $s'= ???$ (where $s'$ is an expression depending on $h, s,$
>   $H,$ and $v$ (You will find that $d$ drops out of your calculation.)
>   Now consider the time at which the rock hits the ground. At that time
>
> $h=s=0$.
>
> The speed of the shadow at that time is $s'= ???$ where your answer is an
>   expression depending on $H, v,$ and $d$.
>
> **Hint**: Use similar triangles and
>   implicit differentiation. For the second part of the problem you will
>   need to compute a limit.

Answer (score 1):

As the problem says, you have similar triangles in the diagram.  You should be able to write an equation $s=$ some function of $h$.  What are the similar triangles?  What are the corresponding parts?  What is the ratio of the sizes?  Now take the derivative of that function with respect to time to get $s'=\frac {ds}{dt}$.  You will need the derivative of $h$, which you are told is $v$.

Comment: I ended up with $(vd)/(H-h)^2$ as $s'$. I feel like my notation is off though. The answer should not have $d$ in the first part of the question.

Comment: Presumably you found $s=\frac {hd}{H-h}$.  You didn't take the derivative properly.  Note there is an $h$ in the denominator.

Comment: Oh yeah..so I got $((hd)'(H-h)-(hd)(H-h)')/(H-h)^2$ but I'm not sure about how to write the notation for the derivatives of these elements.

Comment: Note that $H$ and $d$ are constants, so you don't take their derivatives.  If you expand the numerator, some terms cancel.  I don't get $d$ dropping out and it doesn't make sense to me that it would.  I also don't see needing a limit to evaluate $s'(h=0)$

Answer (score 0):

start with the similar triangles equation s/h= s+d/H then take the derivative, quotient rule for the first side and then jut take the derivative of the top to cancel out the d, H is a constant so it gets pulled out as 1/H. then solve for s' =(Hvs)/(Hh-h^2)